# VSCODE - How to develop a UI like the Twitter Feedback

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In vscode there is a smiley face at the bottom right side of the page.
Does anyone know if there are docs relating to how to develop an extension with a Form-like UI Such as this.

https://www.screencast.com/t/rgIwIO1pVQvv

Answer (score 1):

That is built-in UI. We don't expose it to extensions.

I suggest trying to use existing API functions such as as `showQuickPick` and `showInputBox` if you can. If you really need custom UI, take a look at [html previews](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/previewhtml-sample)

Comment: Hmm will there be any support or is there talk of support in the future for custom UIs.

When building extensions such as chat client's or a redmine client, it makes sense to allow the user to give the consumer a friendly UI to edit. I can see this being a benefit to other extension authors out there.

Comment: Take a look at html previews for custom ui. However VS Code intentionally discourages UI heavy extensions. Consider if you really need custom UI or if there is another way